# Other ways to show a Windows path

Tags: urls

I am writing a technical document, and I need to show a **reference to a Windows path**. As I'm using the url package, and my example is
drive:\directory\directory\file.xls

My code is

```
\path{C:\\directory\directory\file.xls}
```

Is this the best way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: tha's fine, what's your actual qustion, in what way do you want it to be better?

Comment: I wonder if is there other ways to do it: other commands, other packages...

Comment: well of course there are hundreds of ways, without any package at all you could use `\verb|C:\\directory\directory\file.xls|` or you could use listings or minted or fancyvrb or ... it depends what features you want.

Comment: You could always use `\verb|C:\\directory\directory\file.xls|` to typeset the reference, but why?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You just beat me to it with the `\verb`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are several ways. As you have done, and as David and I suggested using `\verb` and then doing it all yourself using basic LaTeX macros.

If you don't like the simple methods provided by LaTeX and its packages then you can take control of everything yourself

```
% urlprob.tex  SE 637691

\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily

C:$\backslash\backslash$directory$\backslash$directory$\backslash$file.xls

\end{document}
```

[image]